# Can't use SOCKS5 proxy over GoogleCloudPlatform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, socks, dante

I've setup a VM instance following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-dante-proxy-on-ubuntu-20-04

The problem is that i can't connect the service that i want using the proxy. I'm using  external_ip_of_vm:port:user:pass . But the proxy doesn't seem to work. When i try to log in on the game that i want, nothing happens, but when i try to connect without proxy, it connects.

I think this can be related to the firewall setting on the GCP. But i don't know how and which rule should i create to get the proxy work.

I'm using port 1080 inside Dante Proxy, as the tutorial. Thanks to everybody who dedicated time to read and i will be thankfully if you can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you likely need only add the port to the firewall (preferably binding only to the instance running Dante) on the port on which you're running Dante (by default, 1080 but it may be good to use a random other port) to permit access (this would replace (!) the `ufw` instruction in the DigitalOcean documentation). Did you use Cloud Console or `gcloud` (Cloud SDK) to configure the VM?

Comment: See [Using firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls). When you create the VM that runs Dante, it is good practice to [add network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) to the instance. Then, when you create the firewall rule, you can e.g. permit TCP on e.g. port 1080 but restrict ingress only to the VM running Dante by matching network tags in the firewall rule with instance tags.